# Google play store like interface using recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My assignment is to create an interface much same like Google Play Store.There will a Category name followed by 3 or 4 cards (horizontal) followed by More button. Then again next category.

I already had implemented this using nesting the horizontal listview inside Vertical listview.

I know, I can achieve this by using the Recycler view with LinearLayoutManager with horizontal orientation. Using this I'll be having one only row.

My question is how do I add 2nd, 3rd row to this?
Should I use again nested Recycler view? 
Are there some better options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont use nested listviews (you cant scroll horizontally in play store).

Consider the following options:

1. You can use a simple LinearLayoutManager and make different view types. For the with 3 cards horizontally use a `GridLayout` or `LinearLayout` with same weights. The problem here is, that you have to consider the indexes of your underlying data list used in the adapter
2. Write your own LayoutManager for RecyclerView
3. Use [TwoWay View](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) which is based on RecyclerView and offers a `Spannable Grid` Layout manager, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Using the TwoWay View, I don't think that I can add the Category name and more button after each row. Isn't it?

Comment: why not? It's a simple  LinearLayout that spans the whole width (all columns).  The label and the more button are not two different cells

Comment: I am not getting the 3rd one. I'll read about that. But first option is good and I can implement that. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

If you inspect the layout of the Google Play app, they do not use a listview/recyclerview for the horizontal cards. I'm pretty sure that is just a linearlayout (horizontal) within a vertical listview / recyclerview.

If you insist on using a horizontal recyclerview for each row, then having a nested recyclerview would be your best option. You can specify a `RecycledViewPool` so that all the nested recyclerviews share the same pool instead of creating their own.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I think using a linear layout within a recycler view will be fine.

Comment: Alex,I think same  that Play store app doesn't  use ListView or recycler View for horizontal cards.  I also sure that  they just use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation  and yes with same  weight for each card. I have worked on nesting recycler View over  Recycler View ,  but i found performance lack. And its  obvious too. But my concerns are how they manage there adapter data for such view??  Do you have any  idea?

Comment: Because what I think is,  by this approach Adapter code complexity will increase drastically. But if we use another list or  recycler  view ,  then Adapter data handling will be clean  but performance will lack.

Comment: i am also faces same problem in here . @MahendraChhimwal Thanks for your insight :)

Answer (score 0):

You may like to do it as one vertical `RecyclerView` (Main recycler) and for every section you can inflate a horizontal `RecyclerView` as well (Section recycler) as this blog answer mention:

Also, consider using:

- A cache layer for `Bitmaps` for persistent access through your other store screens
- A lazy load method for your category/section images
- A place holder before showing new items