# how to add dynamically multiple horizontal listview in android like play store application in android

Tags: java, android, listview, horizontal-scrolling

[image]

I want to add multiple horizontal listview dynamically runtime like google play store application home page in which user can vertically scroll and in listview user can scroll horizontally.

Comment: had you tried anything ?

Comment: no because i don't know how to add listview dynamically and populate it..

Answer (score 2):

Create the layout in your xml:

Then create a new layout for the items that will be in the vertical list, in this instance, you want to fill it with horizontal lists:

Then create a new layout for the items that will be in your horizontal list:

Then simply create list adapters for your vertical and horizontal lists, ensuring that you inflate the correct layout for each list type.
you can then use those adapters to dynamically add lists to the vertical list or images to your horizontal list.

I suggest that before you do any of this, you familiarise yourself with listviews and listadapters.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

The short of it is, you can populate lists with strings by using a SimpleListAdapter, but to populate a list with more complex layouts, you can extend the BaseAdapter class. Follow a few tutorials to get a feel for it.

Comment: Please refer to my answer here: 
[Horizontal RecyclerView Vertical RecyclerView Google Play Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493207/google-play-store-like-interface-using-recycler-view/42503397#42503397)