# How to make row list using recyclerView and card? Can I use Nested RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to design a `row list` using `RecyclerView` like Android TV ↳    `android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ListRow`. I'm able to design list with title but not row list. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please Follow this Link for

[Recycer view like play store](https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html)

Use Two RecyclerView Outer Recycler is vertical and Second horizontal recycler is item of first recycler View 
All you need is to call mInnerRecycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); on your inner RecyclerViews and use Horizontal scrollview as root of mInnerRecyclerView

Explanation:

RecyclerView has support for nested scrolling introduced in API 21 through implementing the NestedScrollingChild interface. This is a valuable feature when you have a scrolling view inside another one that scrolls in the same direction and you want to scroll the inner View only when focused.

In any case, RecyclerView by default calls RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true); on itself when initializing. Now, back to the problem, since both of your RecyclerViews are within the same ViewPager that has the AppBarBehavior, the CoordinateLayout has to decide which scroll to respond to when you scroll from your inner RecyclerView; when your inner RecyclerView's nested scrolling is enabled, it gets the scrolling focus and the CoordinateLayout will choose to respond to its scrolling over the outer RecyclerView's scrolling. The thing is that, since your inner RecyclerViews don't scroll vertically, there is no vertical scroll change (from the CoordinateLayout's point of view), and if there is no change, the AppBarLayout doesn't change either.

In your case, because your inner RecyclerViews are scrolling in a different direction, you can disable it, thus causing the CoordinateLayout to disregard its scrolling and respond to the outer RecyclerView's scrolling.

Notice:

The xml attribute android:nestedScrollingEnabled="boolean" is not intended for use with the RecyclerView, and an attempt to use android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" will result in a java.lang.NullPointerException so, at least for now, you will have to do it in code.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView can check View Type for return header or item. And use layout manager for manage how to item scrolling direction.

RecyclerView (vertical scrolling)
- item -> RecyclerView (horizontal scrolling) check view type is header or item with condition example : is object has type header

Ref : [Google play store like interface using recycler view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28493207/7575602)